# Any reference for good Datamining tools in Java?

Tags: java, database, data-mining

We are working on an internship project for company. The project itself consists of Datamining. Let's say the structure of database we have to work is huge (in Gigabytes).

Sad to say that DB itself is very poorly structured with inconsistent values and most importantly **no primary or foreign keys**. So in our simple Servlet modules to extract and show the inconsistent data, it takes forever for queries to perform and show up on servlet.

As n00b programmers we do not know about Join and such things in DB. Also we are using MySQL as our DB server. The DB is composed of real-time data from telecom towers.

To find sample inconsistency in table values we are using combination of multiple queries, output of one query serving as input to another query like:

`"SELECT distinct(tow_id) FROM  'tower_data' WHERE TIME_STAMP LIKE ? ";`

//query for finding tower-id.

```
"SELECT time_stamp FROM tower_data WHERE 'TIME_STAMP' LIKE ? AND 'PARAM_CODE' = ? AND 'TOW_ID'=? GROUP BY time_stamp HAVING count( * ) >1";
```

//query for finding time stamps with duplicate data.

And so on.

Also there are some 10 tables in the database. We need to combine 2-3 tables to get values for custom queries.

After finding all the inconsistent values for multiple factors, we have to do data cleansing, removal of noise, data prediction and such tasks in the next stage.

So we thought we can apply some Java Data Mining tools which would in turn apply some algorithm to speed up the data retrieval.

Please guide us towards some good datamining tools. Any guidance towards optimizing/rewriting the queries would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the table doesn't have keys or doesn't allow it for some reason, then there's nothing to optimize.

Comment: @BaluC Nothing at all? No algorithms or joins or query techniques that we can use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure it will help in your case, but have a look at [google-refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/)...

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a lot of badly structured data, I do not think data-mining will help.
You may consider using [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) for going over all this data and finding inconsistencies. You can use [Amazon EC2](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonEC2) for a simple and relatively cheap way to run Hadoop. You can also use Hadoop to port the databases to a better schema, provided that you can build one.

EDIT: I guess you can also do some things within MySQL. Use [query explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to find the slow parts of your query - I believe 'LIKE' is usually slow, and maybe you can reformulate the query to something faster. Maybe you can first sort your schema by timestamp and then look at sub-ranges. Again, you first have to have an efficient way to get the data, and then you can try to mine it. Good luck.

Comment: you sure you read our problem and who we are? EC2 is fine but Hadoop for students? Seriously? 

We do not have such resources available with us.

Comment: Yes ! I was talking about number of machines for clustering and nodes. I don't think it will serve much purpose with a single machine with 3 or 4 GB RAM.

Comment: @Anurag - Hadoop is open source. If you have a linux machine, you can install hadoop. However, It is true that Hadoop scales with the number of machines; but the Amazon EC2 with Hadoop is meant for such cases - basically you pay for the computation time - usually running a computation on tens of virtual machines is much cheaper than buying a server.

Comment: what is the entry fee? Time based calculation right? I also heard they provide a free demo for sometime.

Comment: @Anurag - Sorry. I see they only support this in the US and the EU. Here are the prices anyway: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/pricing/ Also, I suggest that if you come along specific problems, you post them as individual SO questions.